# How many items can one buy and bring back home from Japan?

Tags: air-travel, japan, vietnamese-citizens

My friend is about to come home to Vietnam after 1 year working in Japan. Some family members and friends asked her to buy electronics and other stuff for them; she also bought a new laptop and mobile phone for herself.

So what kind of items and how much can she buy in Japan and bring back to Vietnam legally? And what she should do to avoid getting blocked at the airport?

This is her first time going abroad; she and I don't have experience in this area so please tell us anything we need to know.

Comment: Check out https://www.vietnamonlinevisas.com/vietnam-customs-regulations/#:~:text=How%20Much%20Cash%20Can%20I,without%20having%20to%20declare%20it.

Comment: Are you moving to Vietnam or just going there for a short time (holidays/visit family)? The rules are very different…

Comment: @jcaron, the question mentions 'coming home to Vietnam'. Seems clear to me.

Comment: I would point out that it might be worth checking whether sending by mail rather than taking on the plane would be more convenient. It might also decrease potential customs duties, as each parcel would likely be judged individually. Obviously, it's not an option for anything with a lithium battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it in https://www.vietnamonlinevisas.com/vietnam-customs-regulations/

> Items whose total value does not exceed VND 10,000,000

Chances that her personal laptop and phone are exempt since they "personal use" items.

So if the total value of the gifts she is brining exceeds VND 10M, than she needs to declare it and pay import tax on it. This can be pretty complicated and time consuming, so I would check carefully of the savings are really worth it.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow this page. It has no sources or references though.

Comment: For the curious, at today's exchange rate that works out to about USD 430, or a bit under JPY 56000.

Answer (score 2):

There are normally no legal limits, but customs will want dues for everything above a certain amount.
Look up what the free amount for your country is, and what are the customs dues for anything above.

Comment: Can you add where to look for that amount?

Comment: I tried but the respective sites are in vietnamese, I cannot read them or even decide if they are right.